# Powershell Json Array content from Azure DevOps Api

Tags: arrays, json, powershell

```
    {
"count":  3,
"value":  [
              {
                  "id":  "12345678-123456-23424-123456ff2",
                  "name":  "TestProject",
                  "description":  "Test project  migration",
                  "url":  "https://dev.azure.com",
                  "state":  "wellFormed",
                  "revision":  6619,
                  "visibility":  "private",
                  "lastUpdateTime":  "2019-10-14T06:10:03.557Z"
              },
              {
                  "id":  "12345678-123456-23424-123456ff2",
                  "name":  "KC-TestAutomation-Framework",
                  "description":  "Test Automation Frameworks",
                  "url":  "https://dev.azure.com",
                  "state":  "wellFormed",
                  "revision":  6502,
                  "visibility":  "private",
                  "lastUpdateTime":  "2019-10-03T07:53:33.95Z"
              },
              {
                  "id":  "b2345678-123456-23424-12345",
                  "name":  "Training",
                  "description":  "Training Management Project",
                  "url":  "https://dev.azure.com",
                  "state":  "wellFormed",
                  "revision":  7124,
                  "visibility":  "private",
                  "lastUpdateTime":  "2019-12-02T07:19:24Z"
              }
     ]
}
```

I've this Json, I need to create from this json another json containing the name,and ID of every project in this form name:name value:id in json file...

I've tried somenthing like this..

```
   $json = Get-Content $file | ConvertFrom-Json 

   ForEach($i in $json.value.id)
    {
      Write-Host "Id: $($i)","name: $($json.value.name)"
    }
```

Comment: foreach($project in $projects.value)
{
    Write-Output "name:$($project.name)" "value:$($project.id)" *>> $path/.json
}

Comment: This should not be difficult.. What have you tried yourself and why did that not work?

Comment: I Kwow it's easy, but I'm lost... I've tried somenthing like this    
        $json = Get-Content $file | ConvertFrom-Json 

        ForEach($i in $json.value.id)
{
    Write-Host "Id: $($i)","name: $($json.value.name)" 
      }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Read the JSON file and convert it using `ConvertFrom-Json`.
- Select the id and name properties and convert back to json
- Write the newly created json to file

Something like this:

```
$json = Get-Content -Path 'X:\YourJsonFile.json' | ConvertFrom-Json

$newJson = $json.value | Select-Object id, name | ConvertTo-Json

# output on screen
$newJson

# output to new json file
$newJson | Set-Content -Path 'X:\YourNewJsonFile.json'
```

Output:

> ```
> [
>     {
>         "id":  "12345678-123456-23424-123456ff2",
>         "name":  "TestProject"
>     },
>     {
>         "id":  "12345678-123456-23424-123456ff2",
>         "name":  "KC-TestAutomation-Framework"
>     },
>     {
>         "id":  "b2345678-123456-23424-12345",
>         "name":  "Training"
>     }
> ]
> ```